# Centos minumum mouse clicks / keystrokes to create desktop shortcut to folder

Tags: linux, file-shortcut

In my quest to find the linux equivalents to MSFT transactions I am looking for the minimum effort steps to create a desktop shortcut to a folder.

OK, in MSFT Windows file browser :

1. RMB on folder -> Copy
2. Move mouse to desktop area
3. RMB Paste Shortcut

I've checked this in Kubuntu and Centos. Step 1 + 2 are obvious.
But when issuing step 3 there is no 'Paste Shortcut'. The 'Paste' function actually does a full blown copy which is not desired. In Dolphin file browser I can do :

1. RMB on folder -> make Link
2. Link is created in file browser window
3. LMB + hold drag on link to desktop

But it sucks to have the intermediate step where the link clutters the folder.

Any better ideas?

Cheers,
Gert